# Robotics Recommendations

Tags: block-based-programming, robotics

I have a class of 25 students. We want to learn programming robots using a blockly-type programming language. I would prefer having a robot for every student or at least one per every two students. Price is a concern. I would like to spend about max $50 per student.

I am mostly working with middle-school kids (7th and 8th grades). Most have never worked with robots nor have they programmed in any language (including blockly).

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: I incorporated your comment.  A lot of the stuff I'm seeing is for grades k-2, so that's good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Edison Programmable V2.0 Robot. (https://www.robotshop.com/en/edison-programmable-v20-robot.html)  Available from Amazon.  Also Makeblock mBot Robot Kit (Amazon.com)

I have read some articles about the Edison be used in school successfully.  The Makeblock I just saw on Amazon.

Comment: Edison looks like a great robot for starters. Makeblock looks good too and maybe more flexible, but also more expensive. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of micro:bit and kits that companies build for them. For example, [the Tinybit robot from Yahboom](https://category.yahboom.net/products/tinybit). It includes [programming activities](http://www.yahboom.net/study/Tiny:bit). I've bought hundreds of these and had good experiences with 12 - 16 year olds who are new to programming.

Comment: Welcome to [CSEducators.se]! I hope we hear more from you.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! ☺ I appreciate the welcome